# Splitting a Poisson process according to time-dependent probabilities

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a homogeneous Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. Suppose we define functions $p_1(t)$, ..., $p_k(t)$, such that for all $i$ and $t$, $p_i(t)\in [0,1]$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^kp_i(t) = 1$.

Let $Y_1,\dots, Y_k$ be processes. Now, for each arrival to the process $X_t$, choose randomly one of the processes $Y_1,\dots,Y_k$ according to the probabilities $p_1(t),\dots,p_k(t)$ and let this arrival be an arrival into the chosen process.

Does this produce independent, inhomogeneous Poisson processes and if so, how to prove it?

Considering the infinitesimal characterization of a Poisson process, it seems likely, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed this is called *splitting* and the inverse operation is called *merging*. Yes a splitting produces independent Poisson processes with intensities $\lambda_i(\ )$, where $\lambda_i(t)=\lambda p_i(t)$, or $\lambda_i(t)=\lambda(t) p_i(t)$ if the original Poisson process is inhomogenous with intensity $\lambda(\ )$.

A proof for the homogeneous case where $\lambda(t)$ and the $p_i(t)$ are all independent on $t$ is [there](http://www.netlab.tkk.fi/opetus/s383143/kalvot/E_poisson.pdf) and the adaptation of this proof to your case is not difficult. The general case is in many classics on point processes, for instance in section 6.4 *Marked point processes* of *An introduction to the theory of point processes* by D.J. Daley and D. Vere-Jones.

Comment: Do we need to put any assumption on $\lambda(t)$ and $p_i(t)$? Or just Riemann integrability is sufficient?